# C ++ logger Multiple process support logger

Tags: c++, logging

Muliple process access to writing on same file simultaneously..if the file size is excess on the limit(example 10mb),the processing file is renamed(sample.txt to sample1.txt)rolling appender) and create a new one on the same name.

My issue is ,multiple process writing  at same time,File size exceed time file closed, if one of the process is still writing on same file. doesnt File rolling .can any one help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy that I've used also works on a distributed computing system accross multiple machines.

If you create a library which will package log messages and then send them via TCP to a destination, then you can have as many processes as you like writing to the same logger.  You'd need a server at that destination to receive the log messages and write them to one file.

Generally, inter-process communication occurs via either shared memory or networking.  Using networking we can go not-only inter-process, but also inter machine.  If we just use the destination of localhost or 127.0.0.1, then the packet never actually reaches the network card.  Most drivers are smart enough to just pass the packet to any processes listening, leading to good performance too.